# wrong number of arguments - in initialize method

Tags: ruby

I am not able to figure out this extremely simple error:

```
xyz_controller.rb:
    @isbn = params[:q]
    @search_type = params[:search_type]
... 
    @prices = Generalsearch.new(:search_term => @isbn, :search_type => @search_type)

generalsearch.rb

    attr_accessor :search_term , :search_type
    def initialize(search_term , search_type)
      self.search_term= search_term
      self.search_type= search_type
    end
...
```

I keep getting

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
app/models/generalsearch.rb:11:in `initialize'
app/controllers/book_controller.rb:47:in `new'
app/controllers/book_controller.rb:47:in `view'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are passing only one argument ie hash `:search_term => @isbn, :search_type => @search_type` in Generalsearch.new()

use

```
Generalsearch.new( @isbn, @search_type)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use, as you're accepting 2 params on the initialize function, not a hash of of params.

```
@prices = Generalsearch.new(@isbn, @search_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
Generalsearch.new(:search_term => @isbn, :search_type => @search_type)
```

Then you can have in the `initialize` method

```
def initialize(options)
  # You can also use options[:search_term], 
  # but fetch lets you know if the key doesn't exist
  self.search_term= options.fetch(:search_term) 
  self.search_type= options.fetch(:search_type)
end
```